# jquery mobile lost css with ajax post

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, jquery-mobile

I'm creating a mobile app with jQuery Mobile and i've a little problem. I want to create a list with some content from the database wich I get from an ajax post.

The markup looks like this:

```
<div data-role="page">
<div data-role="header">
    <h1>Facturen</h1>
</div><!-- /header -->

<div data-role="content">   
    <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" id="Invoices">
        <div id="invoiceList"></div>
    </ul>
</div><!-- /content -->

<div data-role="footer">
    <h4>Page Footer</h4>
</div><!-- /footer -->
```

This is the jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "invoices/index.php",
        data: '',
        complete: function(data)
        {
            $('#invoiceList').html(data.responseText);
        }
    });
```

Well, I put the results of the query between

but in some way the css doesnt work of the list doesnt work.

if I trie this it worked fine:

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" id="Invoices">
        <li>test</li>
        <li>test</li>
        <li>test</li>
        <li>test</li>
    </ul>
```

Somebody knows how to fix this?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In jQuery Mobile, whenever you update elements there is usually a follow-up step where you trigger an action upon it. For example, when you add new things into an unsorted list, you need to call

```
$('#invoiceList').listview('refresh');
```

This would go immediately after adding these elements into your UL inside the `complete:` callback.

There are various other things you could try as well if this doesn't generate the behavior you're looking for. For example, you might need to execute the [`.append()`](http://api.jquery.com/append/) operation instead of using `.html()`. I've seen that sort of usage more frequently in these sorts of circumstances.

Comment: Wonderful, @LeonvanderVeen; glad your list is getting its css now

Answer (score 0):

Try adding to the `ul` element you `id` as `class` `invoiceList`, because you are appending the `li` elements in the `div` element and formatting will not work:

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" id="Invoices" class="invoiceList">

</ul>

<script>
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "invoices/index.php",
    data: '',
    complete: function(data)
    {
        $('.invoiceList').html(data.responseText);
    }
});
</script>
```

Comment: I already tried that but unfortunately it doesnt work. Maybe it's a jquery mobile problem...